# Is Nobby Cook a real person?

Tags: stan-and-ollie, laurel-and-hardy

I just finished watching [*Stan & Ollie* (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3385524/), the biofilm starring Steve Coogan and John C. Reilly as Laurel and Hardy. In the film, Laurel and Hardy are on a stage tour of England when Hardy falls ill. Their manager suggests replacing him with a comedian named Nobby Cook, played in the film by John Henshaw.

In the film, Stan Laurel experiences a last minute change of heart, and instead of taking the stage with Cook, he has the theatre manager announce to a stunned audience that the show has been canceled.

This seemed out of character for a consummate professional like Stan Laurel, who chronically insisted on giving his fans a show even when he wasn't being paid for it. So I started hunting around to determine how accurate the scene was. I was surprised to find I could find no mention of Nobby Cook other than this film.

Was the Nobby Cook character a fabrication for this film, or was he a real, albeit obscure, British comedian in the 1950s?

Comment: You can try to find something here https://www.myheritage.pl/names/nobby_cook

Answer (score 1):

By all accounts, there was never a Nobby Cook or anyone with whom Stan would have continued the tour.  Some of the facts in these types of films are always changed a bit, 2 that come immediately to mind are that they did *three* tours of the UK and this film combined them into one, and Ollie had a heart attack [after a performance](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-devon-46762940), not while judging a beauty contest.

> After performing a single night at the Palace Theatre in Plymouth,
>   Hardy had a mild heart attack, forcing the duo to cancel their run in
>   the city and the rest of the tour.
>
> Hardy stayed at a local hotel to recover, while Laurel visited the
>   theatre every night to support other acts, Hutchinson said.

The Nobby Cook ruse was just meant to show you how dedicated Stan was to Ollie and add a layer of tension with the possibility of Stan continuing with a new partner.